# Meteor up deployment errors

Tags: meteor, deployment, meteor-up

I am trying to deploy my app to a remote host - it was working fine and suddenly I get a lot of errors.

```
    -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
    ./deps/libexpat/lib/xmltok.c:186:21: note: ‘isName2’ declared here
       int (PTRFASTCALL *isName2)(const ENCODING *, const char *);
                         ^  
-----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
./deps/libexpat/lib/xmltok.c:186:21: note: ‘isName2’ declared here
   int (PTRFASTCALL *isName2)(const ENCODING *, const char *);
                     ^
../deps/libexpat/lib/xmltok.c:890:1: warning: missing initializer for field ‘isName2’ of ‘const struct normal_encoding’ [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
 };
 ^
../deps/libexpat/lib/xmltok.c:186:21: note: ‘isName2’ declared here
   int (PTRFASTCALL *isName2)(const ENCODING *, const char *);
                     ^
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed


 0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: localhost
        Latest deployment failed! Reverted back to the previous version.
        -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
        est@2.51.0, gtoken@1.2.0)

    ../deps/libexpat/lib/xmltok.c:890:1: warning: missing initializer for field ‘isName2’ of ‘const struct normal_encoding’ [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
     };
     ^
    ../deps/libexpat/lib/xmltok.c:186:21: note: ‘isName2’ declared here
       int (PTRFASTCALL *isName2)(const ENCODING *, const char *);
                         ^
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: localhost
    Latest deployment failed! Reverted back to the previous version.
    -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
    est@2.51.0, gtoken@1.2.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be the related thing I would try first.
https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up#updating

...if you need to update your Node version, you'll have to run "mup setup" again before deploying.

You may have easily forgotten that.